# TextBox custom ContextMenu in Style, multithreading error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, textbox

In WPF application I use Textbox with custom style in which ContextMenu is overriden like this:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
      <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
      </ContextMenu>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

This works perfectly until I'll run window with TextBox in different threads like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()=>
                                {
                                TestWindow wnd = new TestWindow();
                                wnd.ShowDialog();
                                });
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

But this causes InvalidOperationException "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.".

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your style is reused as optimization, so the ContextMenu is reused - this is standard and works well for single threaded, but not for multithread.

I would try moving the style to the resourcedictionary and referencing it as a StaticResource, I would then mark with:
x:Shared="false"
This will create a new instance everytime the resource is accessed - I am not sure it works for the "catch all" key less style you have. 
Then you could make the contextmenu a resource and refere it as a StaticResource - that should do it.

Comment: Another solution is to use an eventsetter for rightclick and create a ContextMenu on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

In your piece of code, you want do modify the UI in a non-UI thread, which is not allowed.

You have to make sure you're on the UI thread when applying UI updates. You can check whether this is required by checking the value of `object.InvokeRequired`. If needed, you can invoke the method by calling `object.Invoke([delegate])`.

Besides that you can also use the dispatcher, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx) and [this blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/cschittko/archive/2008/05/14/wpf-ui-update-from-background-threads.aspx). Happy reading